# Rasp's ability on running setup.exe file or windows software

Tags: raspbian, hardware, linux

I really need help with whether there is a way for Rasp. to run windows software. I have a sensor and the software it came with. I want to use Rasp. to run the software which will control the sensor. I tried to run setup.exe on Resp NOODs but it did not work out.

Sincerely,

louis

Answer (score 1):

No. Not only would this be written for a different processor, the format is totally different.

If you post details of the sensor there is probably a Linux driver for it.

Comment: I suppose there is an outside possibility that it may work on a Pi2 with Windows IoT.

Comment: @joan It will still need recompilation. ARM and x86/x64 are still different from each other.

Comment: @PandaLion98 While you're probably right, I'm not sure there's enough information here for you to say that for sure.

Comment: @lwr20 Oh no. I'm pretty sure. The hardware, yes, it may work. The software that came with it (setup.exe) won't. I won't bet my life on the hardware though.

Comment: Has anyone commenting on @joan's comment on my post ACTUALLY tried Windows IoT?

Comment: @Milliways I haven't. PandaLion98 Yes, I keep forgetting a bundled exe will almost certainly be for x86.